# Remove the copied element when a check box is uncheked

Tags: jquery, html

Below pasted code will copy a `<table>` element from one `<div>` to another `<div>` on checking the checkbox. but how can i remove the same element when the checkbox is **uncheked**.

```
  $(":checkbox").on('change', function () {

        if ($(this).hasClass('containerToCopy')) {

            if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
               $(this).closest('div').clone().appendTo("#divTestPrintContainer");

            } else {
              // if #divTestPrintContainer contains the element associated with the checkbox then remove it.                    
            }                
        }
    });
```

Comment: thats right but I have mutltiple <div> s added to #divTestPrintContainer. I need to remove the exact <div> associated with the checkbox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a data parameter to the copied element that is set to the ID of the original check, when the checkbox is unchecked then just find the copied element with the appropriate data value and remove it.

Something like:

```
$(":checkbox").on('change', function () {

    if ($(this).hasClass('containerToCopy')) {

        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
           var myClone = $(this).closest('div').clone();
           myClone.appendTo("#divTestPrintContainer");
           // Here I insert the 'data-id' attribute to the cloned element and assign
           // it the value of the id from the original element.  This is how we match
           // the cloned element with the original.
           myClone.attr('data-id', $(this).attr('id'));

        } else {
          // if #divTestPrintContainer contains the element associated with the checkbox then remove it.
          // Here we find a child element of the #divTestPrintContainer that contains
          // a 'data-id' attribute matching our checkbox id that is being unchecked.
          $('#divTestPrintContainer').find("[data-id='" + $(this).attr('id') + "']").remove();
        }                
    }
});
```

This is assuming that your original elements contain id's to identify each one.

Comment: I dodn't have Id's for the elements.

Comment: It's not hard to assign them elements, just use an incrementing number or something, maybe prefix them with a string to make sure they don't conflict with anything else on the page.  The bottom line is that they need something unique that can be used to identify them apart and that the clone can remember for later use.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should try using `.not(':checked')`.

http://api.jquery.com/not/

Answer (score -1):

```
$('#divTestPrintContainer').empty();
```

http://api.jquery.com/empty/

Comment: The problem with this is that there could be multiple children here, each cloned from a different checkbox.  We only want to remove the one cloned element that belongs to the checkbox that was just unchecked, not all of them.